# Multiple IF's and AND's

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help on a formula.

I want to conditionally format a cell based on it and two other cell values. Basically IF the cell to be highlighted is empty and another cell (with numbers) is larger than 60, highlight red.

This kinda works, but keeps the cell (V2) red even after something is inputted into it.

```
=IF(ISBLANK($U2),"",Q2>60)
```

In a nutshell:

If `U2` is NOT blank but `V2` IS blank and `Q2` is greater than 60, `V2` should go red. But when data is typed into `V2`, there should be no more conditioning.

Any geniuses out there can help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, I *think* this will work for you:

```
=AND(ISBLANK($U2),Q2>60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as a conditional formatting rule for cell `V2`.

```
= AND(NOT(ISBLANK(U2)),ISBLANK(V2),Q2>60)
```

Comment: OMG you're a genius!  This worked EXACTLY the way I needed it.  And now I can apply this to like 10 different columns!

Comment: @TomLawson Please mark my answer as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.